# vuejs подключить jquery и скрипты через файл

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Пытаюсь подключить **wrunner range slider** в компонент используя **jquery**.

```
<template>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="main__input">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="main__input">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="wrunner"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
    import $ from '../scripts/jqueryMin-3.4.1.js'
    import wRunner from '../scripts/wrunner-jquery.js'
    export default {
        mounted() {
            $(".wrunner").wRunner({
                step: 1,
                type: "range",
                limits: {
                    minLimit: 0,
                    maxLimit: 100
                },
                rangeValue: {
                    minValue: 0,
                    maxValue: 100
                },
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

В итоге получаю ошибку

```
error 'wRunner' is defined but never used no-unused-vars.
```

**В чем проблема?**

Comment: _«'wRunner' is defined but never used»_ - это не то чтобы ошибка, это линтер на тебя ругается за то что переменную объявил и не используешь (попробуй просто `import '../scripts/wrunner-jquery.js';`).

Comment: Но вообще, использовать jQuery вместе с реактивной библиотекой - очень, **очень** плохая практика (Vue и React работают с Shadow DOM - поэтому подключением jQuery или работой с DOM напрямую, можно нажить себе массу серьезных проблем и багов). Вместо использования жквери и ее плагинов, лучше будет найти плагины для Vue делающие то же самое: так и ломаться из-за "борьбы библиотек" ничего не будет, и подключать/использовать значительно проще.

Comment: теперь такая ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: решение не юзать jQuery во Vue, никогда....